# Show progress bar for angular mat-stepper on each field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular-material in that am working with mat-horizantal-stepper , instead of showing horizantal line in between, is it possible to show progress bar along with updating the progress on filling of each field in every mat-step

Comment: Yes you can do this.When user change the step you will have `@Output()
selectionChange: EventEmitter<StepperSelectionEvent>` based on that you will get on which step you are. Then calculate the relative % progress for that step and assign that % value to `mat-progress-bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but actually I need a progress bar in between each step and that progress bar should be updated when ever the field data is filled.

Comment: Then you can try something: watch changes on `reactive-form` value change. And increase the progress variable value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try this.

Comment: Did it work? I have the same issue and I don't know if try this or make my own custom stepper...